# JmsListener method not triggered IBM MQ with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

In my Spring Boot application I have to read message from IBM MQ queue and process those messages, but my JmsListener method (method with annotation @JmsListener) not called or triggered and there is no error message in log.
Implementation details are herein

1. I have add these dependencies in pom.xml

> Blockquote

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> Blockquote

2. Added annotations @EnableJms in the spring boot application class
3. Added the server information to the src/main/resources/application.properties file

> Blockquote

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=XXXX
ibm.mq.channel=XXXXXX
ibm.mq.connName=mq-u100-xx.xx.xyz.com(1444)
ibm.mq.user=XXXXX
ibm.mq.password=XXXXX
```

> Blockquote

4. Created Listener class

> Blockquote

```
     @Component
     public class CDBListener {
       @JmsListener(destination = "${mq.queue-name}")
        public void receive(Message message) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
              
            // business logic 
        }
     }
```

> Blockquote

5. Added configuration class

> Blockquote

```
    @Configuration
    public class JmsListenerConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory handlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new 
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

        @Bean
        public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
       }

       @Override
       public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(handlerMethodFactory());
      }

   }
```

> Blockquote

It seems I missed something and due to that this issue, help me to resolve the issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Chughts for your support, finally we resolved this issue by making two small change in code

1. Change the application properties key from mq.queue-name to mq.queueName
2. Listener method name from receive(Message message) to receiveMQMsg(Message message)
3. Remove class JmsListenerConfig as suggested by @Chughts as not in use.

Not sure exactly what was the issue, it might be application property key name causing the problem or Listener method name.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that you are not seeing any error messages, it suggests that nothing is getting through. Have you checked the error logs on your MQ Server on localhost? I am guessing that you are running a container, so based on the cheat sheet at - https://developer.ibm.com/articles/mq-dev-cheat-sheet/

```
docker exec -ti <container_id> /bin/bash
```

and

```
cd /var/mqm/qmgrs/<your_queue_manager_name>/errors/
```

Some observations on your setup.

You have

```
<version>2.0.9</version>
```

which is quite dated, current latest is `2.7.2`

You are listening for a JMS Message then casting it into a `TextMessage`.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "CDB_Queue")
public void receive(Message message) throws JMSException {
    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
              
    // business logic 
}
```

This is unsafe, you should check that the cast is possible before casting.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "CDB_Queue")
public void receive(Message message) throws JMSException {
   if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
       TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
              
       // business logic 
   }
}
```

Your `JmsListenerConfig` doesn't do anything beyond the default, so it isn't actually needed. You can safely remove it.

You can switch on trace on the client side. See https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring#logging--tracing

> You can enable tracing of this specific component in your
> application's properties file by setting
> `logging.level.com.ibm.mq.spring.boot=TRACE`. Otherwise it uses the
> standard inheritance of logging configuration from
> logging.level.rootdownwards.

Comment: `ibm.mq.connName=localhost(1414)` suggests that your Spring App is looking locally.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Its my mistake while posting my query. we are using ibm.mq.connName=mq-u100-xx.xx.xyz.com(1444) in connName not the localhost. We are deploying out code in fabric environment and there we not using following properties as per the fabric deployment team it not required.
ibm.mq.user=XXXXX
ibm.mq.password=XXXXX

Comment: We check by put message on queue to check the access for queue then it throws error host not found, we resolve this issue by whitelisting our server and installed required certificate. Now no error when we put message on queue but JmsListener method still not get called.

Comment: You really need to check logs. If you can obtain them, ask for the server side logs. For obtaining client side logs, check the update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for response, we put log level TRACE but no effect or new messages in application log file(We are using log4j logging)
When put message and read explicitly then there is no error and we not only put message on queue but also able to read message, but jmsListener method not get called we tried a lot. We put and read message with following command
"
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("CDB_Queue");



javax.jms.Message msg = jmsTemplate.receive("CDB_Queue");

"

Comment: We also asked for server log but there only text like
AMQSBCG0 starts here
*****************************
MQOPEN - 'CDB_Queue'

MQGET of message number 1, CompCode: 0, Reason: 0

****Message discription*******
.
>

Comment: The lack of content in the client side trace suggests nothing is happening, and that the trace setting was not read. This does conflict with you managing to get the `convertAndSend` to work I am guessing that the values from application.properties are being used. You mentioned `Fabric`, is that also being used in the `convertAndSend` test?  If you can, try the 101 code from https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Spring-JMS#level-101-sample which is a very lightweight spring JMS put / get